# Catch alternative strings from OR operator with a Regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to catch a certain part of strings where there are alternative Regex branches. How can I safely refer to defined spots in alternative paths. I thought about doing

```
m=re.match("(A(?P<name>.+)B|C(?P<name>.+)D)", text)
match=m.group("name")
```

but there is a conflict with redefining the name. Using `m.group` by an index would be troublesome, since these Regex come from configuration files and I cannot guarantee the nesting level/index value which will lead to the match.

EDIT:
In the setup there are texts to match and regex from separate sources. I'd like to achieve

```
import re

for text in ["ABBC", "DEEEF", "GHHI"]:
    for regex in ["(A(.+)C|D(.+)F)", "G(.+)I"]:
        m=re.match(regex, text)
        if m:
            print(m.group(1)) # should actually match the middle characters, but doesn't work generally
            break
```

The number of possible regex can grow in the future, so it has to be a general solution

Comment: I'm not sure what you can and can't change from your code. From the comment you left on the previous answer, it looks like you can't change the regex?

Comment: I can define the required syntax for the Regex. But even then there are *multiple independent Regex* and it's hard to reliably generate a single huge Regex as suggested in the answer?

Comment: I think a possible solution is to use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/2014.11.14 . Not sure if I miss a standard way...

Comment: How about using `re.findall`? That way you get a list of matches and I guess you can filter out the empty strings that you will get. Otherwise, the `regex` module would indeed be a solution where you can use the same named group.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use lookahead assertions. If you replace `(A(.+)C|D(.+)F)` regex with

`^(?=A.+C$|D.+F$)[A-Z](.+)[A-Z]`, then `group(1)` will generally match middle characters.

It says: if you are at the beginning of a string (`^`) and one of lookahead assertions within `(?=...)` succeeds, match `[A-Z](.+)[A-Z]` string.

Answer (score 0):

Your example can be made to work by changing

```
            print(m.group(1))
```

to

```
            print(filter(None, m.groups())[0])
```

(simply taking the group which contains the match).